# Solving a PDE (2D Laplacian) coupled with an ODE

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, heat-equation

I have asked this question before, but this is my new attempt and so instead of cluttering the previous one, I am making a new post. I am trying to *analytically* solve a PDE ($\nabla^2 T(x,y)=0$) coupled with an ODE. The PDE is subjected to the following boundary conditions:

$$\frac{\partial T(0,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial T(L,y)}{\partial x}=0 \tag 1$$

$$\frac{\partial T(x,0)}{\partial y}=\gamma \tag 2$$

$$\frac{\partial T(x,l)}{\partial y}=\beta (T(x,l)-t) \tag 3$$

where $t$ is governed by the ODE:

$$\frac{\partial t}{\partial x}+\alpha(t-T(x,l))=0 \tag 4$$

subjected to $t(x=0)=0$. I am trying separation of variables. I manipulated $(4)$ to express $t$ as $t=\alpha e^{-\alpha x}\Bigg(\int_0^x e^{\alpha s }T(s,l)\mathrm{d}s\Bigg)$ and substituted in $(3)$ while applying the 3rd b.c.

My attempt is (I must acknowledge Bill Watts here as I have used methods I learned from his answer on MMA SE):

```
pde = D[T[x, y], x, x] + D[T[x, y], y, y] == 0

(*product form*)
T[x_, y_] = X[x] Y[y]
pde/T[x, y] // Expand
xeq = X''[x]/X[x] == -a^2
DSolve[xeq, X[x], x] // Flatten
X[x_] = X[x] /. % /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2}
yeq = Y''[y]/Y[y] == a^2
DSolve[yeq, Y[y], y] // Flatten
Y[y_] = (Y[y] /. % /. {C[1] -> c3, C[2] -> c4})

(*addition form*)
T[x_, y_] = Xp[x] + Yp[y]
xpeq = Xp''[x] == b
DSolve[xpeq, Xp[x], x] // Flatten
Xp[x_] = Xp[x] /. % /. {C[1] -> c5, C[2] -> c6}
ypeq = Yp''[y] + b == 0
DSolve[ypeq, Yp[y], y] // Flatten
Yp[y_] = Yp[y] /. % /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> c7}

T[x_, y_] = X[x] Y[y] + Xp[x] + Yp[y]
pde // FullSimplify

(*Applying the first and second b.c.*)
(D[T[x, y], x] /. x -> 0) == 0
c6 = 0
c2 = 0
c1 = 1

(D[T[x, y], x] /. x -> L) == 0
b = 0
a = (n π)/L
$Assumptions = n ∈ Integers

(*Applying the third b.c.*)
(D[T[x, y], y] /. y -> 0) == γ
c4 = c4 /. Solve[Coefficient[%[[1]], Cos[(π n x)/L]] == 0, c4][[1]]
c7 = c7 /. Solve[c7 == γ, c7][[1]]
T[x, y] // Collect[#, c3] &

(*now splitting T[x,y] into two parts*)
T[x, y] /. n -> 0
T0[x_, y_] = 2 c3 + c5 + y γ /. c5 -> 0
Tn[x_, y_] = T[x, y] - T0[x, y] // Simplify

(*applying the fourth b.c. to each part individually and using orthogonality*)

bcfn0 = (D[T0[x, y], y] /. y -> l) == β (T0[x, l] - α E^(-α x) Integrate[E^(α s) T0[s, l], {s, 0, x}])
Integrate[bcfn0[[1]], {x, 0, L}] == Integrate[bcfn0[[2]], {x, 0, L}]
Solve[%, c3]
c3 = c3 /. %[[1]]

bcfn = (D[Tn[x, y], y] /. y -> l) == β (Tn[x, l] - α E^(-α x) Integrate[E^(α s) Tn[s, l], {s, 0, x}])
Solve[Integrate[bcfn[[1]]*Cos[(n*Pi*x)/L], {x, 0, L}] == Integrate[bcfn[[2]]*Cos[(n*Pi*x)/L], {x, 0, L}], c5];
c5 = c5 /. %[[1]];//FullSimplify
T0[x_, y_] = T0[x, y] // Simplify
Tn[x_, y_] = Tn[x, y] // Simplify
```

Now we declare some constants and compile the functions

```
α = 62.9/2;
β = 1807/390;
γ = 3091.67/390;
L = 0.060;
l = 0.003;

T[x_, y_, mm_] := T0[x, y] + Sum[Tn[x, y], {n, 1, mm}]

Plot[{Evaluate[T[x, 0, 10]], Evaluate[T[x, l/2, 10]], Evaluate[T[x, l, 10]]}, {x, 0, L}]
```

The plot results are extremely ambiguous. The solution is not even converging (as I increase the number of terms , the `T` value keeps increasing). I cannot figure out what I have done wrong. Since the $T$ results are completely out, I have not calculated $t$. I cannot figure out what I have done wrong.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the t[0] == 0 condition is correct?

Comment: If it helps, then this condition can be taken as $t=t_i$ Then the $t$ differential equation evaluates to  $$t=\alpha e^{-\alpha x}\Bigg(\int_0^x e^{\alpha s }T(s,l)\mathrm{d}s+\frac{t_i}{\alpha}\Bigg)$$ $t_i$ is a constant whose value can be taken as `300`

Answer (score 1):

I can fix the problem of your solution increasing with increasing `n`, but that will not give you a solution.  Rather than copy your entire solution I will start where I think the problem starts.

You have

```
T0[x_, y_] = 2 c3 + c5 + y γ /. c5 -> 0
```

Change that to

```
T0[x_, y_] = 2 c3 + c5 + y γ /. c3 -> 0
(*c5 + γ y*)
```

Then

```
Tn[x_, y_] = T[x, y] - T0[x, y] // FullSimplify
(*2 c3 Cos[(π n x)/L] Cosh[(π n y)/L]*)
```

In your case you were carrying an extra constant term `c5` with `Tn` which was being added for every term in your sum which is why your solution increased with each term.  In my case I carry `c5` as the constant term, but only with `T0`.  The changes below will require changing solving for `c5` with `bcf0` and solving for `c3` with `bcfn`.

This next problem I fear is insurmountable with the calculation of `bcfn0`.

```
bcfn0 = (D[T0[x, y], y] /. y -> l) == β (T0[x, l] - α E^(-α x) Integrate[E^(α s) T0[s, l], {s, 0, x}]) // FullSimplify
(*γ E^(α x) == β (c5 + γ l)*)
```

Examining this result, it is obvious that there is no constant value `c5` can take to satisfy this equation.

Furthermore,  with the new `Tn` the orthogonality equation will result in `c3 = 0`.  This means that `T` will have no `x` dependence, which when you think about it makes sense, if `T` is to satisfy Laplace eq and have `x` derivatives equal to zero at both ends in the `x` direction.

If `T` has no `x` dependence, then its derivatives can also have no `x` dependence, but with the `y` derivative of `T` depending on `t` which has `x` dependence, we have a problem.

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks. I had actually tried with `c3->0`, to reach a `Tn=0` scenario. But I had no idea why in my present solution I had no convergence. But this became clear from your explanation in this answer. I think the problem lies with the convective type b.c. which seems physically correct, but is causing problems.

Comment: Also, have you had any success with the cross-flow problem ?

Comment: I had the exact same problem with the 3D problem.  Tn = 0 and T0 not satisfying the bc.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra  I do not believe that this problem has a solution.  You might consider posting it to Mathematics.StackExchange, because it looks more like a math than a Mathematica problem.

Comment: @bbgodfrey You mean analytical solution, right ? Already tried on MSE, but unfortunately could not get any answers.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra  No, I believe that there is no answer at all.  `T[x, y]` must have a `Cos[n x Pi/L] ` dependence in `x`, with `n` a non-negative integer, so `t` must too.  However, the ODE for `t` mixes `Sin` and `Cos` terms.  This is an interesting problem, and I would be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks for the explanation. This problem describes flow of a fluid over a solid block heated from the bottom using a constant heat flux. There is a solution to this problem in an article where this problem is solved, but their approach was not easy for me to understand. So I was trying the method I have posted. You can find the paper [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CvyNyQk_IDLTUTY3lvaaPXGqhddbUVNx/view?usp=sharing). The solution is elaborated in Section 4, 4.1 and 4.2.  A major difference is that they use flux continuity instead of the robin type conditions

Comment: @IndrasisMitra  I see what you mean about the article being difficult to follow.  But, is it correct?

Comment: @bbgodfrey This paper is pretty well cited (~371 citations) so the results might be correct. Although I must say here that most of the citations refer to the *reduced model* (1-D solid temperature) from the paper and not the complete model (2-D solid temperature) that I am trying to solve here. Also their method is not completely analytical as it involves numerical Laplace inversion.

Comment: Very interesting.  That paper solves the diffusivity equation with an initial temperature and finds the steady state solution by letting time go to infinity.  That initial condition may be what is missing from your problem to make it solvable.  You might try solving their problem with separation of variables.  Their use of transforms does not mean it cannot be done another way.

Comment: @BillWatts Thanks for the suggestion !!! Let me try this. I did not think about it.

Comment: @BillWatts Also if you get the time, give it a try.

Comment: @bbgodfrey BillWatts .I found another alternative solution to this problem in an old paper [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ukjhf1-BZXL6OLdJRHjlpa5Qv-ez0h1f/view?usp=sharing). They have considered the fluid temp. two dimensional. However, I could not follow how they reached Eq. 16.

Comment: I will look at it when I get the chance to to do so in detail.  I think this paper does a better job on details, than the other one, but we'll see.  As far as the other paper, if you don't have the Stehfest algorithm, you can find it at https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/2691/ if you haven't discovered it already.

Comment: @BillWatts From the paper (by Sel et al, 1966) I tried to use the solid temp distribution they provide in Eq. 3 with my fluid equation, but again ran into $Tn=0$ scenario. Thanks for the link to the algo implementation, I will have a look now.